# How to have pagination in spring boot JPA starting with 1 not from 0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I'm trying to have pagination starting from page 1 and not from 0. I have tried having `one-indexed-parameters` but with that number in response still comes as 0 even though in request I can pass page=1 and get page 0 data. How can I achieve that?

```
one-indexed-parameters: true
```

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1815
Seems there is an open issue on the same

Answer (score 1):

This is the frontend code in thymeleaf

```
<div th:if="${totalPages > 1}">
        <div class="row col-sm-10">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                Total Rows: [[${totalItems}]]
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, totalPages)}">
                        <a th:if="${currentPage != i}"
                           th:href="@{'/home/page/' + ${i}}">[[${i}]]</a>
                        <span th:unless="${currentPage != i}">[[${i}]]</span>  &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}"
                   th:href="@{'/home/page/' + ${currentPage + 1}+ }">Next</a>
                <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Next</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}"
                   th:href="@{'/home/page/' + ${totalPages}}">Last</a>
                <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Last</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the controller code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

 @GetMapping("/")
    public String showAllBlogs(Model theModel){

        return findPaginated(1,theModel);
    }

    @GetMapping("/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(@PathVariable(value = "pageNo") int pageNo, 
                           Model model) {
        int pageSize = 3;

        Page<Post> page = blogService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize);
        List<Post> listPosts = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());
        }
        return "blogs";
    }
```

This is the code for service

```
@Override
    public Page<Post> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize);
        return blogRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

I wish this code will help you to resolve the issue.